# Elasticsearch timestamp range doesn't work

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I have Logstash as only input with the following filter and output:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { "message" => "^%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}%{GREEDYDATA:message}$" }
  }

  date {
    match => [ "timestamp", ISO8601 ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    index => "logstash-%{[@metadata][beat]}"
    hosts => [ "${ES_HOSTS}" ]
    user => "${ES_USER}"
    password => "${ES_PASSWORD}"
    cacert => '/etc/logstash/certificates/ca.crt'
  }
}
```

When I try to do a range query over the timestamp it doesn't matter what I do, I always get the same result (that is not within the range specified). Example query in ruby code:

```
params = {
  query: {
    range: {
        "timestamp": {
          gte: "2022-09-22 17:00:00",
          lte: "now"
        }
    }
  },
}

response = ApiClient["_search"].post(
  params.to_json, content_type: 'application/json', accept: 'application/json'
)
```

Response, no matter what I pick in "gte" is (printing [hits][hits][_source][timestamp]):

```
2022-09-22 13:21:53,759
2022-09-22 13:21:53,762
2022-09-22 13:21:53,762
2022-09-22 13:21:53,773
2022-09-22 13:22:08,510
2022-09-22 13:22:51,219
2022-09-22 13:22:51,239
2022-09-22 13:22:51,247
2022-09-22 13:22:51,267
2022-09-22 13:23:04,325
```

I am able to get more / different results if I add size/from in the params. Very new to the entire ELK stack so it is probably something obvious, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi Schoel, could you provide us with the mapping of the `timestamp` field please ?

Comment: Can you share what you get from `GET logstash-*/_mapping` and update your question with the result?

Answer (score 2):

I have two leads from what I see of your query, the first being to use a timestamp in iso8601 format in your query, as this is the format of the timestamp field.

```
            "gte":"2022-09-22T17:00:00",
            "lt":"2022-09-24T12:00:00"
```

The second is to use `"@timestamp"` instead of `"timestamp"`, with the `@` character.

Comment: Thanks! Changing "now" to a timestamp iso8601 or otherwise gives me no results, no matter what times I put in.
Adding an @ to the "timestamp" gives me 400 Bad request as reply.

Comment: Oh great! So how did you make it work exactly, I would update my answer with your information to help someone else in the future :)

Comment: It's not working but produces different results. Changing "now" (i.e. lte) to a timestamp gives me no results at all no matter what times I put in.